# Remove values from array

Tags: php

I have array:

```
$array = array('aaa', 'bbb', 333, 'ddd', 555, '666');
```

I would like remove all values where key is > 3;

How is the best way for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$array = array_slice($array, 0, 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use array_slice() [see documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

Answer (score 3):

You can use foreach loop

```
foreach($array as $key => $image) {
    if($value > 3) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_splice($array, 3);`

May be it will be the easiest way.